# Axios - Multiple file uploads is not working as expected

Tags: node.js, express, post, axios, multer

I need to send text data and images from a form submission to my NodeJS server using Axios(v0.21.0).

I am using the FormData object to append files and axios API for POST request with data as the mentioned FormData object.
This works fine when a single file (image in my case) is uploaded or one of the multiple files alone is passed to axios data (ex- .files[1]).

**This is my index.js:**

```
const form = document.querySelector('.form')
if(form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('images', document.getElementById('images').files)    // Line - 7 (console logged the element and it contains all the image files selected.) 
        
        addFiles(form)
    })
}
```

**This is the module of axios API call:**

```
import axios from 'axios'
export const addFiles = async data => {
    try {
        const res = await axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/resources',
            data
        })

        if(res.data.status === 'success') {
            console.log('Files added')
        }  
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

**This is my html form**

```
<form class="form">
  <input type="file" multiple accept="image/*" name="images" id="images">
</form>
```

Note: I am using multer package for processing the images.

When using Postman for the request, there is no issue with multiple files(images), the issue arises when I use axios to hit my api.
When I upload multiple files and request via axios, the req.files have - [] in the multer's middleware.
But when I send like .files[0] instead of .files in Line - 7 (index.js), the req.files have the specified indexed image.

Uploading of a single file as no issues, as the req.file contains the image.
Tried setting the headers of axios as mentioned in various posts as well as copied header values from Postman but still not resolved.
Where am I missing.